# Google Maps polyline duplication

Tags: xml, setinterval, polyline

I am trying to make a google map using data from xml files.
Every certain time, I am checking if there are any new information and so to display them.
I create a polyline connecting the markers. The problem is that because of the "setInterval", the script creates a new polyline over the existing polyline.

Here is my code:

```
            setInterval(function(){
                downloadUrl("xml.php?id="+polyDevID+"&start=0", function(doc) {                     
                    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
                    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                    var path = [];

                    for (var ii = 0; ii < markers.length; ii++) {
                        var points = markers[ii].getElementsByTagName("devid");
                        // obtain the attributes of each marker
                        var lat = parseFloat(markers[ii].getAttribute("lat"));
                        var lng = parseFloat(markers[ii].getAttribute("lng"));
                        var devID = parseFloat(markers[ii].getAttribute("devid"));
                        var rDate = parseFloat(markers[ii].getAttribute("date"));
                        var TrackID = parseFloat(markers[ii].getAttribute("TrackID"));
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                        // create the marker
                        var marker = createPointer(point,devID,rDate,TrackID);

                        path.push(point);

                    }                                                       
                        //  create polyline
                        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                            path: path,
                            strokeColor: "#"+pColor,
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeWeight: 3,
                            icons: [{
                                icon: direc,
                                offset: '50%',
                                repeat: '100px'}]
                          });
                          polyline.setMap(map);


                });
            },5000);
```

How can I avoid this problem, causing the polyline to be duplicated and so on?

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, there is:

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({ ....
```

what creates a new Polyline and adds it to the map each time your update function is running. To avoid the »dublication« you have two choices:

1. remove the old one, before/after the new one is created, or
2. update the existing one.

In either case you need to keep a reference to the (old/last) Polyline you have created. this can be done like so (first option):

```
(function () {
    var polyline = null;

    setInterval(function(){
        //your code from above until: 

         //  remove polyline
         if (polyline !== null) polyline.setMap(null);

         //  create polyline
         polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
             path: path,
             strokeColor: "#"+pColor,
             strokeOpacity: 1.0,
             strokeWeight: 3,
             icons: [{
                 icon: direc,
                 offset: '50%',
                 repeat: '100px'}]
             });


         polyline.setMap(map);


    }, 5000)
})();
```

In order to use option 2 (reuse existing polyline) this should work:

```
(function () {
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({ … });

    polyline.setMap(map);

    setInterval(function () {
        //your code
        //instead of creating a new line
        polyline.setPath(path);


    }, 5000);

})()
```

[Polyline Docs on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polyline)

I hope it helps!